# Excel VBA Creation error

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to write a macro to read a spreadsheet.  Whenever someone is one year or later with a task, it will send their supervisor email.

I figured out how to send one email per person to a supervisor, but I wonder if I can scan all people and add them to one email.  I tried to modify it, but I could not get it (this is my second day of VBA, hehe)

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("D").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value) = "yes" _
       And LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value) <> "send" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Reminder"
            If Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value = "YES" Then
                .body = Cells(cell.Row, "B") & " " & Cells(cell.Row, "A")
                .Send

                On Error GoTo 0
                Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value = "send"
                Set OutMail = Nothing

    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you would just have to move that ".Send" to out side of the loop, so only AFTER it's gone through the whole range, and added the information you want in the body, THEN it'll send the email.  Also, you could edit the loop to have the body iterate over itself with the new information.  Does that make sense?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to move the .send to the end of the loop, after the next cell, but it still gives me a "next without for" error.  I am actually trying to have the loop iterate with new information, as my final objective is one email with everyone on my list that is "delinquent."

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but let me know how it works:

```
Sub test()
Dim OutApp        As Object
Dim OutMail       As Object
Dim cell          As Range
Dim bodyText      As String  'this is new

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

bodyText = ""

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("D").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And LCase(Cells(cell.row, "E").Value) = "yes" And LCase(Cells(cell.row, "H").Value) <> "send" Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next

        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Reminder"
            If Cells(cell.row, "E").Value = "YES" Then
                'The next line should add the text, and a new line character, so the next cell that needs this will simply be added to the string
                bodyText = Cells(cell.row, "B") & " " & Cells(cell.row, "A") & vbCrLf
            End If
        End With

        On Error GoTo 0
        Cells(cell.row, "H").Value = "send"
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

OutMail.body = bodyText
OutMail.Send

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```